# Best way to refer index which contains in array

Tags: php, arrays

In php I'm willing to check the existence of indexes that match with another values in array.

```
$indexes = array("index", "id", "view");
$fields = array(
    "index" => 5,
    "id"    => 7,
    "form"  => 10,
    "date"  => 10,
);
```

MY ideal result is, in this case, to get "form" and "date". Any idea?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try

```
$fields_keys = array_keys($fields);
$fields_unique = array_diff($fields_keys, $indexes);
```

The result will be an array of all keys in `$fields` that are not in `$indexes`.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this.

```
<?php
 $indexes = array("index", "id", "view");
 $fields = array(
  "index" => 5,
  "id"    => 7,
  "form"  => 10,
  "date"  => 10,
);

$b = array_diff(array_keys($fields), $indexes);
print_r($b);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a little unclear but I think this is what you're going for

```php
array_keys(array_diff_key($fields, array_fill_keys($indexes, null)));
#=> Array( 0=>"form", 1=>"date" )
```

See it work here on [tehplayground.com](http://tehplayground.com/#4e38d7ba213d9)

[array_keys(A)](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php) returns the keys of *array A* as a numerically-indexed array.
[array_fill_keys(A, value)](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-fill-keys.php) populates a new array using *array A* as keys and sets each key to *value*
[array_diff_key(A,B)](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff-key.php) returns an array of keys from *array A* that do not exist in *array B*.

**Edit** turns on my answer got more complicated as I understood the original question more. There are better answers on this page, but I still think this is an interesting solution.

Comment: This would only work if `$indexes` also was associative: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff-key.php - Cool method though!

Comment: @OverZealous, wups, I overlooked that. Have no worry though, `array_fill_keys()` to the rescue!

Answer (score 1):

You can use array_keys function to retrieve keys of a array

Eg:

```
$array = array(0 => 100, "color" => "red");
print_r(array_keys($array));
```

Outputs

```
Array
(
    [0] => 0
    [1] => color
)
```

[PHP Documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php)

Answer (score 0):

There is probably a slicker way than this but it will get you started:

```
foreach(array_keys($fields) as $field) {
    if(!in_array($field, $indexes)) {
        $missing[] = $field;
    }
}
```

Now you will have an array that holds form and date.